# SSRS - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: sql, reporting-services

This doesn't Work:
[image]

This does work:
[image]

Query problem:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: Please read the guide on [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more information

Comment: @baudsp  With respect, all the relevant information is actually already present in the question.  The error message is the error message you would receive in this situation and from that message anyone who has used SSRS to a reasonable extent would know what the problem was.  This is then backed up by the screenshot showing the full query.

Comment: @iamdave Ok. Thank you for your remark and I appreciate you taking the time to say where I am wrong. I will try to do better in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You have two columns with the heading `Name`.

This works in the text editor because you are just running the query, but when you try to click 'Ok' on the `Dataset Properties` window it tries to make the dataset.  This fails because column names need to be unique.

If you change the first line of your query to `select D.Name as DName, O.Name as OName` your dataset should be created properly.